# New values for dublicated usernames - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some dublicates of usernames in my table. I want to give these new unique usernames.

To find the dublicated values, I did:

```
SELECT 
    UserName,
COUNT 
    (UserName) UserName_count
FROM 
    NewUsers
GROUP BY 
    UserName
HAVING COUNT 
    (UserName)> 1;
```

What is the proper way of creating new values to these specifically?

Comment: Whatever solution you end up with you should figure out how/why it happened in first place (if you dont already know) and fix the code so it does not again happen after you fix current data.

Comment: But a user knows and actually uses that name for a purpose. How do you intend to notify the ones you change? And if you simply append or slightly alter the name, doesn't that create a security risk since that tells the associated people that other users have/had the same name?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a suffix based on `row_number()`.  Assuming no existing users have names than end with `_<number>`, then:

```
with toupdate as (
      select nu.*,
             row_number() over (partition by username order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from NewUsers nu
     )
update toupdate
    set username = concat(username, '_', seqnum - 1)
    where seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: what specifices the Table name? t?

Comment: `String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.` does not seem that the table have been updated though?

Comment: @Leo . . . Then expand `username` so it can handle wider values.  Or suggest some other method for choosing user names.  This is my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for effort, much appreciated as I learned about row number func. Might as well be helpful for someone else.